# Spring Data Rest как отключить обертывание коллекций в ссылки

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Как отключить обертывание коллекций с зависимостями (в моем случае Set) в ссылки в теле ответа? пояснение ниже.

Есть сущности со связями @OneToMany и @ManyToOne
Есть репозиторий наследованный от JpaRepository
Приложение на СпрингБут, все работает на спринг дата. То есть контроллеры и сервисы спринг имплементирует сам. Для наглядности ниже классы Owner и Cat

```
@Entity
public class Cat{

    @Id
    Long Id;

    String catName;

    @ManyToOne(...)
    Owner owner;
```

Класс хозяев

```
@Entity
public class Owner{

    @Id
    Long Id;

    String ownerName;

    @OneToMany(...)
    Set<Cat> pets;
```

Все работает, классы создаются, в сет коты тянутся. В JSON формате вывод выглядит так:

```
{"id":"1",
"catName":"Barsik",
"owner":"Valera"}
```

и у хозяина

```
{"id":"1",
"ownerName":"Valera",
"pets":[{"id":"1",
    "catName":"Barsik",
    "owner":"Valera"}]}
```

НО(!) Spring Data выдает данные в формате HAL+JSON, и вывод хозяина выглядит так

```
{"id":"1",
"ownerName":"Valera",
"_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/owners/1"
        },
        "lot" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/owners/1"
        },
        "pets" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/owners/1/pets"}
}}
```

Я очень благодарен спрингу за заботу, и то что он построил рест для меня, но мне нужно работать с моделью, когда кот вложен в хозяина в одном JSONe.

ВОПРОС:Как отключить обертывание коллекций с зависимостями (в моем случае Set) в ссылки в теле ответа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать проекции ([Projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts)).

Например, было так:

```json
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
    },
    "address" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
    }
  }
}
```

После добавления проекции

```java
@Projection(name = "inlineAddress", types = { Person.class }) 
interface InlineAddress {

  String getFirstName();
  String getLastName();
  Address getAddress(); 
}
```

стало так:

```
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "address" : {
    "street": "Bag End",
    "state": "The Shire",
    "country": "Middle Earth"
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
    }
  }
}
```

Для получения результата с проекцией, нужно к запросу добавить параметр **projection**:

```
http://localhost:8080/persons/1?projection=inlineAddresses
```

Если подключить проекцию к репозиторию по умолчанию (называется [Excerpt](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts)), например:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = InlineAddress.class)
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

то параметр к запросу можно не добавлять. Но это справедливо только для списков. Для получения одного объекта нужно все равно указывать параметр **projection**.

Чтобы отключить HAL можно воспользоваться [этими](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23287265/5380322) рекомендациями автора Spring Data REST.

Answer (score 2):

Тебе надо пометить свой интерфейс, наследованный от `JpaRepository` (или какого-то подобного) как `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`.

---

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264044/spring-data-rest-disable-hypertext-application-language-hal-in-json-applica).

Comment: Тогда по этому репозиторию не строится рест. У меня ведь не реализованы вручную ни контроллеры ни сервисы. Меня интересует какой-нибудь конфиг или что-то в этом роде, который отключает обертывание контента в ссылку внутри ResponceBody. То есть не отключить HAL полностью, а лишь вывести коллекции в т ело ответа